# Start Chrome in Application Mode

Tags: macos, high-sierra, google-chrome

How do I do the following equivalent of Windows on a Mac?

```
"path\to\chrome\chrome.exe" --app=http://facebook.com
```

[Link to Windows question](https://superuser.com/questions/33548/starting-google-chrome-in-application-mode).

There used to be a [lifehacker guide](https://lifehacker.com/5611711/create-application-shortcuts-in-google-chrome-for-mac-with-a-shell-script) to do this but unfortunately some of the links in the guide are dead.

Comment: could you tell us (just for the record) what Mac and what OS is it.

Comment: /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --app="http://www.google.com"

Comment: sorry missed that, your Tags said High Sierra, so I changed that

Comment: https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier App solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will open Google Chrome with the specified URL:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --app="https://example.com"
```

Comment: almost except it should have separate icons in the dock like Windows.